# Modify Excel Pivot Table without knowing pivotTable name in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

I would like to use the following with a variable in place of "PivotTable1".

```
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("row1")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 1
End With
```

I have gotten around it by adding a prompt for the table name like this

```
pivotName = "PivotTable" + InputBox("PivotTable#?", "Pivot Name", "1")
ActiveSheet.PivotTables(pivotName).PivotSelect
```

but would like to make it cleaner with one less step. Is there any way to dynamically populate the `pivotName`?

Comment: What is your criteria for populating the name?  Would it be the only one on the sheet?  Does a user need to select it?

Comment: It will be the only one on the sheet and when it is created, a new sheet is created as well. So it will always be at default "A3".

Comment: If it will always be the first one created on the sheet you can simply refer to it by the index number 1. `ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1)`